# Creating an HTML document out of RichTextBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

I am having issues creating an html document out of a RichTextBox. I am able to get all of the text out of the RichTextBox. This issue is when I go to get images that I pasted in by using Windows Snipping tool don't show up in the document. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Convert the content to byte array, save it and try it

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could give us a non-working example where the error occurs in order to help you. Anyway, you could also check [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Converting-between-RTF-and-aaa02a6e) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter) out.

Hope I helped!

Comment: The issue is that the first example wont get pasted Images that are in the Rich TextBox. This line: var textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd); Only will return the text in the Rich TextBox and not the images